# Do I need to have taken differential equations to understand the Cauchy Riemann equations?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a soft question: I have just finished a two semester sequence of real analysis where I covered topics such as sequences and series, point set topology, continuity, differentiability, and integration (all in $\mathbb{R}$). I am taking a course in complex analysis next semester which has analysis as a prerequisite, but I saw that the Cauchy--Riemann equations are differential equations which must be satisfied for something to be holomorphic.

Does one generally need ODEs and PDEs to take a standard undergraduate course in complex analysis?

Comment: No. If the prerequisites say 'Analysis', you can expect to learn everything else you need in the course.

Comment: Questions seeking advice for choosing a course, etc are off-topic, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @MartinR I disagree that this falls under that category,  as it isn't personal advice,  but a more general "Does topic X require knowledge of topic Y", which is a concrete question with a concrete answer

Comment: @Alan: The question specifically asks whether a certain course should be taken as a  prerequisite to another course. In my opinion, that falls under the off-topic category *“Questions seeking personal advice for choosing a course, academic program, career path, etc. **Such questions should be directed to those employed by the institution in question,** or other qualified individuals who know your specific circumstances.”*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No,  the CR equations are just taking a function and checking that some equations involving partial derivatives are equal.  A course in ODEs and PDEs involves taking equations involving derivatives/partial derivatives and trying to solve for the original function.   It's basically the opposite direction of what you need (and the much harder one!)